# Use Visitor or Listener with ANTLR4 when returning objects of different types

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I translate one language into another with ANTLR4. For example when I read numerical literals I can return an `Integer` or `Double`.

```
@Override
public Integer visitIntegerValue(Parser.IntegerValueContext ctx) {
    return Integer.valueOf(ctx.getText());
}

@Override
public Double visitDoubleValue(Parser.DoubleValueContext ctx) {
    return Double.valueOf(ctx.getText());
}
```

Ultimately if you extend this approach further and introduce other constructs like strings and conditions, the only reasonable type for the visitor is `class Visitor extends BaseVisitor<Object>`, but it leads to a code heavily spiced with `instanceof`. For example

```
@Override
public CollectionQuery visitCondition(Parser.ConditionContext ctx) {
    Property property = (Property) visit(ctx.property());
    String operator = (String) visit(ctx.operator());
    Object value = visit(ctx.amount());
    Object condition;
    if (value instanceof String && operator.equals("$regex")) {
        condition = Pattern.compile((String) value, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }
    ...
}
```

While I don't mind this kind of 'dynamism', I would like to know if this is a maintainable way to proceed or are there other techniques that I should use instead, like creating proper hierarchy of target language constructs.

Comment: I'd go with a custom post-processing step. So you have a return type that matches the need for each rule. It isn't that much more to do and it will be worth the time. As you already stated it's clearer because you don't have to type-cast etc. Just ensure that you don't miss a case in a rule (best I found so far to do this is a sample input file that triggers every case of a rule and assertions that check if each subrule is triggered).

Comment: Do you think you could give me a link to an example? It's my first project with ANTLR and I would really like to get it right. Thank you!

Comment: I've got no real code handy but posted a sample pseudo code snippet to give you an impression how it could look like. The stuff in a method looks almost the same except you have no common signature (e.g. "result value") and need to handle the child calls yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion is to have a visitor per return type:

```java
public class IntegerVisitor extends BaseListener<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer visitIntegerValue(Parser.IntegerValueContext ctx) {
    return Integer.valueOf(ctx.getText());
  }
}

public class DoubleVisitor extends BaseListener<Double> {
  @Override
  public Double visitDoubleValue(Parser.DoubleValueContext ctx) {
    return Integer.valueOf(ctx.getText());
  }
}
```

This makes more sense when you're visiting vastly different things (for example if you were parsing using a java grammar you might have a `MethodVisitor` and a `ClassVisitor` etc. See an example here: [See an example here](https://jakubdziworski.github.io/java/2016/04/01/antlr_visitor_vs_listener.html)

Answer (score 2):

To get an impression how a custom post-processing could look like.

some ANTLR code

```
topMostRule : childRule+ EOL;
childRule : variantOne | variantTwo;
variantOne : 'A';
variantTwo : '1';
...
```

Pseudo code for a custom postprocessing (more C# like than Java / not the real method names ANTLR uses):

```
public class MyCustomPostprocessor
{
    private IntermediateResults lookupTable; // use private fields for lookup tables etc.

    public ResultType process(Parser.TopMostRuleContext ctx)
    {
        // inspect the children
        var children = new List<object>();
        foreach (var rule in ctx.ChildRules)
        {
            switch (rule.Type)
            {
            case typeof (Parser.ChildRuleContext):
                var result = process(rule);
                children.Add(result);
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException("Don't know what to do with " + rule.Type.ToString());
            }

            // use the information gathered so far to form the result
            return new ResultType (children);
        }
    }


    public object process (Parser.ChildRuleContext)
    {
        foreach (var rule in ctx.ChildRules)
        {
            switch (rule.Type)
            {
            case typeof (Parser.VariantOneContext):
                var result = process(rule);
                return result;
            case typeof (Parser.VariantTwoContext):
                var result = process(rule);
                return result;
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException("Don't know what to do with " + rule.Type.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

    public string process (Parser.VariantOneContext ctx)
    {
        return ctx.GetText();
    }

    public int process (Parser.VariantTwoContext ctx)
    {
        return Int.Parse(ctx.GetText());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a Value class for wrapping the different kinds of objects, and then use this value class as generic type for the visitor.

```
Visitor<Value> visitor;

public class Value {
    private Object value;

    public Value(Object object) {
        this.value = object
        if (!(isDouble() || isInteger))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }


    public boolean isDouble() {
        return value instanceof Double;
    }
    public Double asDouble() {
        return (Double) value;
    }

    public boolean isInteger() {
        return value instanceof Integer;
    }

    public Integer asInteger() {
        return (Integer) value;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // generate hascode
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // equals
    }
}
```